# using bit-wise operation to invert only the MSB of a binary number

Tags: assembly, x86, bitwise-operators, masking

I'm trying to figure out a best way to invert only MSB of a binary number and leaving other bits unchanged, given that the MSB is set.

for example if a binary number is 1111

I tried to and only the first half of ax which is ah, with 00b

```
and ah, 00b
```

which i get 0011, as you can see the bit next to MSB also changes when i did that

how should I change only the most significant bit without changing other bits?

thank in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `AND` doesn't really invert any bits; it *clears* them.

If you want to invert the most significant bit of `AX` you can do this:

```
XOR AX,8000h
```

or for the most significant nibble:

```
XOR AX,0F000h
```

or the most significant byte:

```
XOR AX,0FF00h
```

and so on.

Comment: may I ask why are we using 8000h ?

Comment: `8000h` is `1000000000000000b`. It's just much more convenient to write bitmasks in hex than in binary (or decimal).